# Is there a bosonic representation of Clifford algebra in (1,3) spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, bosons, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra, anticommutator

By a suitable combination of Dirac's $\gamma_\mu$ matrices one can define creation and destruction operators satisfying fermionic anticommutators. Is there a similar result for bosons in the context of Clifford algebra. My interest, at present, is confined to $(1,3)$ spacetime.

Comment: Google "symplectic Clifford algebra". There are tons of papers around. Take for example "Boson algebra as a symplectic Clifford algebra" here: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.527756.